# Hann Window Over a Set of Audio Samples Distorts the Signal - iOS granular synthesis

Tags: ios, sampling, windowing

I'm making a granular synth in iOS, essentially looping very short micro samples, to create new otherwise impossible sounds. To do this I've set up recording and playback capabilities in Core Audio but what is being played back and looped are short samples from a grain buffer.

My problem is that as I'm taking samples from an arbitrary point in the recording, the beginning and end points of the looped sample are not necessarily a zero crossing point. Hence this can result in a click every time the sample begins again, which is very often in granular synthesis. I've tried to fix this by windowing the sample using a hann function, however when I tested this the result was a distorted mess. Note that for ease of testing my grain buffer is 22050 samples long (1/2 a second).

```
// Window over entirety of the grain
for (int i = 0; i < 22050; i++)
{
    // Hann window function, this is used as it zeros at beggining and end of window
    double window = 0.5 * (1.0 - cos((2.0 * M_PI * i) / (22050 -  1)));

    // Applying window
    windowedGrain[i] = grainBufferNew[i] * window;
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Is the windowedGrain buffer meant to contain more samples than the grain buffer? Have I written the hann function wrong? Or Have I not applied the window correctly? Any advice that could be given would be appreciated.

Cheers

UPDATE: I've since further tested the problem, setting window = 1 results in an undistorted but un-windowed sound. I've also used a simple triangular window function instead but this is also distorted see below

```
SInt16 sampleSizeGrainBuffer = sizeof(grainBufferNew)/sizeof(SInt16);    

double window = 0.0;

double increment = 1.0/(sampleSizeGrainBuffer/2);

for (int i = 0; i < sampleSizeGrainBuffer; i++)
{
    // Simple triangular window function
    if (i<(sampleSizeGrainBuffer/2)) window += increment;
    else window -= increment;


    // Applying window
    windowedGrain[i] = grainBufferNew[i] * window;
}
```

UPDATE: The error seems to be due to the final multiplication as grainBufferNew is a SInt16 and window is a double. The two need to be equatable mathematically in order to get it to work properly. As the window function can't be a SInt the buffer data must first be made into a double. Then after this sum it must be converted back to a SInt 16.

UPDATE: I tried casting the grainBuffer as a double but the result was still distorted, despite the result looking fine in the terminal.

```
// Applying window
    windowedGrain[i] = (SInt16)(((double)grainBufferNew[i]) * window);
```

I also tried just casting the grainBuffer as a double

```
// Applying window
    windowedGrain[i] = ((double)grainBufferNew[i]) * window;
```

I tried casting the window to a SInt16, but the result was silence as made the window function to always equal zero.

```
 // Applying window
    windowedGrain[i] = grainBufferNew[i] * ((SInt16)window);
```

I then tried to equate the sizes of the two integers using

```
windowedGrain[i] = grainBufferNew[i] * (window * sizeof(SInt16));
```

Again the result seemed to be windowing in the terminal but the output was distorted

Comment: Hi, any luck with this? I would like to build a granular synth for iOS and It would be great if you could share your progress.